# How do I add files generated during the build to my include directory?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to use a Python script to generate some header and source files for my C++ code and move them to the appropriate source directories, as the subsequent C++ build requires them.

Here's what the current iteration of my code looks like :

```
# Generate the Parameters and ParamParser files.
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT include/waveparameters.h
         include/waveparser.h
         src/waveparser.cpp
  DEPENDS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/scripts/wave.json
  COMMAND python3 ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/scripts/genParams.py ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/scripts/wave.json
  COMMENT "Generating custom Parameters files"
  VERBATIM USES_TERMINAL
)

add_custom_target(PAR_GENERATION
  DEPENDS include/waveparameters.h
          include/waveparser.h
          src/waveparser.cpp
)

set(MULTIGRID_INCLUDE_FILES
    include/waveparameters.h
    include/firstorderwave.h
    include/waveparser.h
   )
set(MULTIGRID_SOURCE_FILES
    src/multiGridTest.cpp
    src/firstorderwave.cpp
    src/waveparser.cpp
   )

set(SOURCE_FILES ${MULTIGRID_INCLUDE_FILES} ${MULTIGRID_SOURCE_FILES})
add_executable(MultiGridTest ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_include_directories(MultiGridTest PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
target_include_directories(MultiGridTest PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
target_link_libraries(MultiGridTest oops ${EXTRA_LIBS} m)
```

The current code generation works just fine.

However, no matter what directory I specify for the output (including `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include` or `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/MultiGrid/include` and related paths), the generated `.h` and `.cpp` files always get moved to the directory my binary is generated in :

```
${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/MultiGrid
```

rather than :

```
${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}MultiGrid/include` and `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/MultiGrid/src
```

Comment: Presumably you need to pass the required paths to your python script. you don't seem to be doing that at present. IIRC the OUTPUT section just tells the build what files to expect as output from the custom command, it has no effect on the custom command itself.

Comment: So, the Python script builds the output files in the `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/script` directory, and CMake is moving them to the binary directory. It's definitely doing something, but I don't quite understand how or why.

Comment: CMake don't move the generated files. They are created there by your python script. You aware that the COMMAND in the `add_custom_command` is run with the **binary directory** being as current one, don't you? If you want to change current directory, then set `WORKING_DIRECTORY` option for `add_custom_command`.

Comment: So is it temporarily copying my Python script into the binary directory, then running it?

Comment: It's doing something like this:

```cd ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} &&
python3 ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/scripts/genParams.py ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/scripts/wave.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out a while ago using Tsyvarev's advice in the comments. The solution was to add `WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` as an argument to `add_custom_command`.